Blazor WebAssembly: Move Authentication and Authorization templated code failed
I moved authentication and authorization from identity template of recently updated visual studio to my blazor webassembly (client-server) web application. Unfortunately, I got errors when completed movements of classes and other code elements.
Below is list of what I've done.
AccountController.cs: (debugged, here is all ok)
[HttpPost]
[Route("/api/account/login")]
public async Task<SignInResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
{
    var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);

    return result;
}

PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider.cs: (not enter here on login at all, is it ok?)
internal sealed class PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider : ServerAuthenticationStateProvider, IDisposable
{
    private readonly PersistentComponentState state;
    private readonly IdentityOptions options;

    private readonly PersistingComponentStateSubscription subscription;

    private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationStateTask;

    public PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider(
        PersistentComponentState persistentComponentState,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        state = persistentComponentState;
        options = optionsAccessor.Value;

        AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
        subscription = state.RegisterOnPersisting(OnPersistingAsync, RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly);
    }

    private void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        authenticationStateTask = task;
    }

    private async Task OnPersistingAsync()
    {
        if (authenticationStateTask is null)
        {
            throw new UnreachableException($"Authentication state not set in {nameof(OnPersistingAsync)}().");
        }

        var authenticationState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var principal = authenticationState.User;

        if (principal.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            var userId = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType)?.Value;
            var email = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType)?.Value;

            if (userId != null && email != null)
            {
                state.PersistAsJson(nameof(UserInfo), new UserInfo
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    Email = email,
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        subscription.Dispose();
        AuthenticationStateChanged -= OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
    }
}

PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider (on authentication always empty return, on access to site pages, required authorizetion - not enter this class method):
public class PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private static readonly Task<AuthenticationState> defaultUnauthenticatedTask =
Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity())));

    private readonly Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask = defaultUnauthenticatedTask;

    public PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider(PersistentComponentState state)
    {
        if (!state.TryTakeFromJson<UserInfo>(nameof(UserInfo), out var userInfo) || userInfo is null)
        {
            return; // always goes here
        }

        Claim[] claims = [
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userInfo.UserId),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Email),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userInfo.Email) ];

        authenticationStateTask = Task.FromResult(
            new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                authenticationType: nameof(PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider)))));
    }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() => authenticationStateTask;
}

Server persistence provider registered at server Program.cs, another provider registered on client Program.cs. Mismatch with templated project is that Login.razor view in my project placed on client, but in template-generated - on server.
Feeling that I've missing something simple - the thing why PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider not entering in debugger at all.
Registration code (client):
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider>();

Registration code (server):
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDataContext>((options) =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(databaseConfig?.ConnectionString);
});
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>()//options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDataContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddScoped<UserManager<User>>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, PersistingServerAuthenticationStateProvider>();


According to your shared code snippet it seems your
Login method in AccountController on the server seems correct, but ensure that the Blazor client calls this endpoint correctly. Would you kindly check if the server responds as expected. In addition, make sure the middleware orders are correct. Do you have application log? Is there anything insightful there? Please double check the trace state changes when the request has been sent.

I'm having the exact same issue, did you solved and remember what it was?

@Santiago Exact copying of broken code leads to exactly same issues, that's truth.
